# In ASP.NET 3.5, what is the .Tag Namespace?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5

I am using TextBox1.Tag + TextBox1.Text for a calculator but the Tag part is not accepted. What namespace must I use for it to be accepted in an ASP.NET 3.5 application?

Comment: It's nothing to do with namespaces. And it would be better if you posted the error message you're getting, instead of just saying "is not accepted".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be thinking about Windows Forms rather that ASP.NET

The Tag property is a property on the [System.Windows.Forms.Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx) which isn't a Web Control.
Have a look at the
   [System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.aspx)
   for information on the available
   properties.